# HTML/CSS Navigation Bar items disappear on window resizing

Tags: html, css

I have a relatively simple menu bar in HTML/CSS. Everything seems to be working fine, but when the browser window is sufficiently narrow, all the items on the nav bar disappear! I'm not sure what part of the code is doing this - I've messed around a bit with the CSS to try and fix it but I haven't had any luck so far. Any pointers or suggestions are very welcome!

An example of the issue at http://www.tomstarley.com/website/accord/pages/home.php - try making it narrower!

HTML

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/navbar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/default.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='home.php'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='aboutus.php'><span>About Us</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='aboutus_ethos.php'><span>Ethos</span></a>
         </li>
         <li><a href='aboutus_mediator.php'><span>Mediator</span></a>
         </li>
    <li><a href='aboutus_testimonials.php'><span>Testimonials</span></a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='mediation.php'><span>Mediation</span></a>
<ul>
         <li><a href='mediation_whatismediation.php'><span>What is Mediation?</span></a>
         </li>
         <li><a href='mediation_howdoesitwork.php'><span>How does it work?</span></a>
         </li>
        <li><a href='mediation_divorce.php'><span>Divorce</span></a>
         </li>
         <li><a href='mediation_cohabitants.php'><span>Cohabitants</span></a>
         </li>
         <li><a href='mediation_children.php'><span>Children</span></a>
         </li>
        <li><a href='mediation_finance.php'><span>Finance</span></a>
         </li>
      </ul>
</li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='costs.php'><span>Costs</span></a>
<ul>
         <li><a href='costs_fees.php'><span>Fees</span></a>
         </li>
    <li><a href='costs_packages.php'><span>Packages</span></a>
         </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href='faqs.php'><span>FAQs</span></a></li>
<li class='last'><a href='links.php'><span>Links</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#cssmenu {
  position: relative;
  height: 22px;
  background: #009ACD;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #009ACD;
  height: 32px;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 500;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > #menu-button {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-out;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 32px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu li.has-sub::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub::after {
  right: 10px;
  top: 20px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover::after {
  border-top-color: #000000;
}
#indicatorContainer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
#pIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  z-index: -2;
  -webkit-transition: left .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: left .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: left .25s ease;
  -o-transition: left .25s ease;
  transition: left .25s ease;
}
#cIndicator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #2b2f3a;
  top: -12px;
  right: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease, top .25s ease;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 37px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  top: 44px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 170px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  width: 130px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #009ACD;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .35s ease;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease;
  transition: all .35s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: #f6f6f6;
  color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.submenuArrow {
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub::after {
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #9ea2a5;
  right: 10px;
  top: 12px;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease, right 0.2s ease;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover::after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
  right: -5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenuArrow,
  #cssmenu #indicatorContainer {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul {
    height: auto;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu li,
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul > li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu ul .has-sub::after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    width: auto;
    padding: 8px 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
    background: none;
    color: #8c9195;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 50px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 65px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 80px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul ul ul ul a {
    padding: 8px 95px;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > #menu-button {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button > a {
    padding: 14px 20px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul.open li,
  #cssmenu > ul.open > li {
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul.open > li#menu-button > a {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.1);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #7a8189;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #7a8189;
    right: 20px;
    top: 15px;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #7a8189;
    right: 20px;
    top: 25px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul.open #menu-button::after,
  #cssmenu ul.open #menu-button::before {
    border-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a media query pointing to a max-width of `800px` that makes the main menu's unordered list disappear with a `display: none`.

Basically, the media query is making the browser load a new CSS `display` value on the menu's list items. By making an element´s `display` equal to `none` you are telling the browser stop displaying it, thus making this element disappear.

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {

#cssmenu li, #cssmenu > ul > li{
   display: none
}
```

**By removing this line you will get an horizontal menu stretching along the site's full width**, which I assume is what you are looking for, is it not?

---

If you want to understand more about media queries and how they work you can read about it on this excelent post on the subject - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: that says `block` not `none`

Comment: @3rror404 ups, sorry, copied the wrong line! I've updated the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Line 198 in navbar.css. You are hinding the `li`'s when the screen is less than 800px

```
#cssmenu li, #cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `navbar.css`

```
#cssmenu li, #cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: none;
}
```